# HOW CAN GET JSON DATA AND SORT IT BY PYTHON

Tags: python, json, for-loop, python-requests

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
When I use order:print(html.text),get all jsondata:
[{"Site":"屏東(琉球)","county":"屏東縣","PM25":"6","DataCreationDate":"202 0-04-19 03:00","ItemUnit":"μg/m3"},
{"Site":"臺南(北門)","county":"臺南市" ,"PM25":"25","DataCreationDate":"2020-04-19 03:00","ItemUnit":"μg/m3"}, ....................................

## If I use order: for Site in jsondata:.....,I only get data:

SITE：基隆CYTY：基隆市P25：21DATE：2020-04-19 14:00UNIT：μg/m3
Why? thank you for your answer sincerely

```
import json
import requests
url1 = '[https://opendata.epa.gov.tw/ws/Data/ATM00625/?$format=json][1]'
html = requests.get(url1)
# html.encoding = "BIG5"
html.encoding = html.apparent_encoding
# print(html.text)
jsondata = eval(html.text)
# jsondata = json.loads(html.text)
for Site in jsondata:
    Sitename = Site["Site"]
    countyname = Site["county"]
    PM25name = Site["PM25"]
    DataCreationDatename = Site["DataCreationDate"]
    ItemUnitname = Site["ItemUnit"]
print("SITE：" + Sitename + "CYTY：" + countyname + "P25：" + PM25name + "DATE：" + DataCreationDatename + "UNIT：" + ItemUnitname)
```

Comment: the URL doesn't look correct

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, also please turn off your caps lock

Comment: @GeorgeMesis so what is the error?

Comment: Please edit your question and place there your explanation of what the error is, and what you expected instead. Then delete the comment. It is better for everyone to read.

Comment: @GeorgeMesis is printing only one-time the error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Always remember not to use `eval()` when you have `json.loads()`:

```
import json
import requests
url1 = 'https://opendata.epa.gov.tw/ws/Data/ATM00625/?$format=json]'
html = requests.get(url1)
html = html.decode('utf8')
html = json.loads(html)
for Site in html:
    Sitename = Site["Site"]
    countyname = Site["county"]
    PM25name = Site["PM25"]
    DataCreationDatename = Site["DataCreationDate"]
    ItemUnitname = Site["ItemUnit"]
    print("SITE：" + Sitename + "CYTY：" + countyname + "P25：" + PM25name + "DATE：" + DataCreationDatename + "UNIT：" + ItemUnitname)
```

Comment: @KunalMukherjee i feel like am a victim of downvote. so many today. i'll bring this to the attention of moderators tommorow

Comment: this approach seems correct to me, as you're doing both the decode into UTF-8 and json.loads